# Field property? what is that?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

So in this video, he talks about making property some sort of "Field" for the new blender api
https://youtu.be/Mjy-zGG3Wk4?t=108

but what is that field? I dont find reference on any web page. seems like no one used that in the history of python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are type declarations, and were [introduced in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep526). Blender 2.80 uses those to create the RNA properties. It was implemented by Campbell in [11 July 2018](https://developer.blender.org/rBS09aa799e5331a9da666f8a6325b038a866b1f35d).

Comment: How could that extend if we create dynamic class using type() ? I have been scratching my head around this lately : type(“TestPropGrp”, (bpy.types.PropertyGroup,), {‘MyProp’:StringProperty(default=‘MyStr’)}) thx !

Comment: Interesting question. Not something to discuss in comments though,but deserving its own question.

Comment: Thx !  You're right, this definitely deserve its own question. I'd love to have your thoughts on this - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118118/blender-2-8-field-property-declaration-and-dynamic-class-creation