# Blender 2.8 - Field property declaration and dynamic class creation

Tags: python

Now that we need to use field for property declarations in Blender 2.8. I was wondering how this can be done when creating class dynamically using type() like so:

```
type('TestPropGrp', (bpy.types.PropertyGroup,), {‘MyProp’:StringProperty(default=‘MyStr’)})
```

=> this would work in Blender 2.8 but will throw a 'make field' warning.

Any idea how to declare field when using type() ?

Thank you !

edit (this is actually wrong - see answer): Of course one way to do it is to write this in 2 lines:

`clss = type('TestPropGrp', (bpy.types.PropertyGroup,), {})`

`clss.myProp : StringProperty(default=‘MyStr’)`

but I was wondering if there could be a more compact solution ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The annotations for an object (which can be a class or a function as well) are stored in its `__annotations__` property, as defined by [PEP 526 and introduced in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-526-syntax-for-variable-annotations). This gives rise to the following solution:

The following approach works as I suspect you're looking for:

```
>>> clss = type('TestPropGrp2', (bpy.types.PropertyGroup,), {
...     '__annotations__': {'myProp': (StringProperty, {'default': 'MyStr'})}
... })
>>> print(clss.__annotations__)
{'myProp': (<built-in function StringProperty>, {'default': 'MyStr'})}
```

This also allows you to see that your proposed "one way to do it" approach doesn't actually work as intended:

```
>>> clss = type('TestPropGrp', (bpy.types.PropertyGroup,), {})
>>> clss.myProp : StringProperty(default='MyStr')
>>> print(clss.__annotations__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'TestPropGrp' has no attribute '__annotations__'
```

Comment: Thx Sybren! I’m still confuse with the use a field property but that will help. I need to test but There is si till some blurred case like what would be the init value if you declare: myProp: bpy.props.StringProperty(default=‘MyString’) = ‘myString2’.

Comment: You wouldn't pass `default='MyString'`, I think. Just write clear, unambiguous code ;-)

Comment: Well that is the way we were passing a default value for StringProperty before so it means that now with  field property this doesn’t make any sense. BTW, This notation would end up with myProp having a value of ´myString’.

Answer (score 6):

I’ll extend Sybren's answer above with a warning, after some bug just found in our `@orientation_helper()` IO class decorator today (see https://developer.blender.org/T58772 ). It does not directly affect your example, but it could in some slightly different dynamic class generation cases.

Do ensure you have an `__annotations__` dict defined in the class you want to add fields to! Otherwise:

- **If one of your parent classes defines it**, you will actually add the field to that parent's `__annotations__` dict, effectively adding that field to all the children classes as well, and not only the one you wanted to.
- If there is no `__annotations__` defined anywhere in parent's hierarchy, you'll just get an error (which is much simpler to debug than the first case).

Bug linked above leaded to *all* IO add-ons using `ImportHelper` as parent of their Import operator to display the Up/Front axes selectors, even though they would not need them. We had to switch from that (simplified code):

```
def orientation_helper(axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z'):
    def wrapper(cls):
        cls.__annotations__['axis_forward'] = StringProperty()
```

…to that:

```
def orientation_helper(axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z'):
    def wrapper(cls):
        # Without that, we may end up adding those fields to some **parent** class' __annotations__ property
        # (like the ImportHelper or ExportHelper ones)! See T58772.
        if "__annotations__" not in cls.__dict__:
            setattr(cls, "__annotations__", {})

        cls.__annotations__['axis_forward'] = StringProperty()
```