# How can I create multiple variables in a PropertyGroup?

Tags: python

I want to create a number of StringProperty's to a property group using a loop.
e.g:

```
class Test(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    for n in range(1, 20):
        line_[n] : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "line_%d" % (n))
```

I tried enumerating a list but it registers the list too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Annotations**

Quite possibly this is a dupe of [Blender 2.8 - Field property declaration and dynamic class creation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118118/blender-2-8-field-property-declaration-and-dynamic-class-creation)

I found that using the `type` method do define a class in 2.79 was very handy, but for annotations very tricky.

If an `__annotations__` is defined on our propertygroup class, can add to it prior to registering.

```
import bpy

class Test(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    __annotations__ = {}

for n in range(1, 20):
    k = "line_%d" % n
    Test.__annotations__[k] = bpy.props.StringProperty(name=k)

bpy.utils.register_class(Test)
bpy.types.Scene.test = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Test)
```

Or in the class

```
class Test(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    __annotations__ = {'line_%d' % i: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="line_%d" % i) 
            for i in range(1, 20)}
```

Test in py console

```
>>> C.scene.test.line_1
''
```