# Create a list of string properties

Tags: python, add-on, import

I'm looking for a way to have a dynamic amount of string properties.
currently I have setup an array which appends a bunch of string properties to a list, this is all fine and well except i can't place the property in the layout due to it not having an identifier (well not that i know of).

```
    for _ in self.MATERIAL_LIST:
        self.TEXTURE_PROPERTIES.append(props.StringProperty(name=_, description='{} texture'.format(_)))       
        imageBox.prop(self.properties, 'TEXTURE_PROPERTIES')
```

above you can see I have a Material list which is a list of all the names of the materials

I wish to place each elemt of the array in a UIlayout box called 'imageBox'
any help is appreciated and even alternative or more efficent ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**`imageBox.prop(self.properties, 'TEXTURE_PROPERTIES')`
causes an error as TEXTURE_PROPERTIES property cannot be found

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130911/how-can-i-create-multiple-variables-in-a-propertygroup  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118118/blender-2-8-field-property-declaration-and-dynamic-class-creation  (probable dupes)

Comment: Will look into it thank you. Gonna have to test it soon

Comment: I had better success with adding a class of property group, however I am struggling to placing properties defined in __annotations__, I have no problem placing `imageBox.prop(self.TEXTURE_PROPERTIES, 'prop1')`

but if i had something like

`self.TEXTURE_PROPERTIES.__annotations__['mat_0'] = props.StringProperty(name = 'Material 0')`
`imageBox.prop(self.TEXTURE_PROPERTIES, 'mat_0')`

I have no success

,also if I define the annotations in the class and not later I have no problems