# Duplicate properties from existing operator and add to PropertyGroup

Tags: python

I'm writing an addon that needs to have the same properties as another operator (i.e the Alembic exporter properties). But I'm not sure how to register them? Normally I create a PropertyGroup and add my properties in the **init**.py file.

```
class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_bool: BoolProperty(
        name="A bool",
        description="",
        default = False
        )

    etc...
```

But how do I add properties that I have in a list?

```
def get_alembic_props():
    props = []

    for prop in bpy.ops.wm.alembic_export.get_rna_type().properties:
        # In this example, just add bools.      
        if prop.type == "BOOLEAN":
            new_prop = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
                identifier = prop.identifier,
                name=prop.name,
                description=prop.description,
                default=prop.default
            )
    
    return props

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    abc_props = get_alembic_props():
    for prop in abc_prop:
        ...somehow add the prop...
```

Also, is it correct to use the `operator.get_rna_type().properties` to get the properties of another operator? It seems like the all return something called `_PropertyDeffered`.

Comment: You have to define all properties similar to `alembic_export` into your `PropertyGroup`

Comment: Yes, but as I show in the example it's unclear to me how to define a property (dynamically) in a loop. I don't want to hardcode the values.

Comment: You should hardcode the property which you need and leave the rest

Comment: I agree that trying to dynamically retrieve another operator's props in another op can be problematic. I would go to the file where the operator is defined in your blender install and just copy/paste the properties. Requiring an operator to be registered in another operator's definition is a recipe for error because of how unpredictable registering is. However if you really want you can dynamically define operators using this method https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/56741/86891

Comment: It's not great to hard code the properties, as they are updated pretty often, i.e the USD exporter. There's a lot of if/else statements depending on versions and it will always be required to update the addon when something changed in for example the USD exporter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to work [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130911/how-can-i-create-multiple-variables-in-a-propertygroup). Not sure if there are any problems in doing it like this?

```
class AlembicProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    # Basic example, just supporting BoolsProperty
    __annotations__ = {x.identifier: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name=x.identifier, default=x.default) for i in get_alembic_props()}
```