# Simple python code does not work

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, customization, properties

Not sure why this simple code does not work. I tried several things... but it only works if the values are *statics* . In this example I put one *dinamic* value (does not work) and another that works but is burned.

Code:

```
import bpy

#create prop_group
props = {
    "name" : [],
    "type" : [],
}

#add props 
props["name"].append( "fl_prop" )
props["type"].append( "float" )

print("---" )
class CustomPropGr(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    global props
    
    for name in props[ "name"] :
        for type in props[ "type" ] :
            
            if type == "float" :
                print("debug:: name : ", name, " type: " ,type )
                name : bpy.props.FloatProperty( name = name )
            # end if
            
        # end for
    # end for
    
    no_dinamic_prop : bpy.props.FloatProperty( name = "test" )
    
# end CustomPropGr
bpy.utils.register_class( CustomPropGr )


#make it enable and discovery for all objects
bpy.types.Object.custom_prop_gr = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CustomPropGr)


so = bpy.context.active_object

so.custom_prop_gr.no_dinamic_prop = 5.90
so.custom_prop_gr.fl_prop         = 90.5
print( "no_dinamic_prop    : ", so.custom_prop_gr.no_dinamic_prop )
#comment the below line to see the outputs
print( "dina prop (fl_prop): ", so.custom_prop_gr.fl_prop )
print("---" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Python's `type` method for dynamic props**

Recommend using python's type for dynamically creating classes.

Here is an example.

- Set up two float properties "foo" and "bar" in our props dictionary.  Both are given "float" as a type. Have converted to bpy prop by simply making it title case "Float" and tacking "Property" to the end, then grabbing that type via get attribute from `bpy.props`.
- For the non dynamic members have set up some class to define these.
- Then using `type` create a class, give it the name we wish to define, the inherited classes, lastly `PropertyGroup`.
- Finally The annotations, *ie* our dynamic props are added in the last argument.

Test script.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import (
        PointerProperty,
        FloatProperty,
        )
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup

props = {"foo" : "float",
         "bar" : "float",
         }

class NonDynamic:
    test : FloatProperty(name="Bar")
         
Group = type(
        "CustomPropGr",
        (NonDynamic, PropertyGroup,),
        {'__annotations__' :
            {
                
                k : getattr(bpy.props, f"{v.title()}Property")(name=k)
                for k, v in props.items()
            }
        }
    )
    
bpy.utils.register_class(Group)

bpy.types.Object.foobar = PointerProperty(type=Group)
```

Test run python console.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> C.object.foobar
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].foobar

>>> str(C.object.foobar)
'<bpy_struct, CustomPropGr("") at 0x7f5b1a793f68>'

>>> C.object.foobar.foo
0.0

>>> C.object.foobar.bar
0.0

>>> C.object.foobar.test
0.0
```

Notes: can see from this can extend this quite simply to create a method that dynamically creates classes. I often use this to create `AddonPreferences` class from the addons  underlying modules.

Have used a dictionary instead of the two separate lists for name and type, if using the two lists suggest using zip

```
for k, v in zip(props["name"], props["type"]):
    ...
```

Related:

[Blender 2.8 - Field property declaration and dynamic class creation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118118/blender-2-8-field-property-declaration-and-dynamic-class-creation)

Comment: I can't read some little thinks of the code... Why the for is down and not in top? what is "annotations" and... in what moment you put the name foobar ? how i can change it?  zip is very usefull !!! and the dictionary is better aproach. Thanks friend!

Comment: import bpy

class Class (bpy.types.PropertyGroup) :
    non_dinamic : bpy.props.FloatProperty()

props = {
    "dinamic1" : "Float",
    "dinamic2" : "Float" }

setattr( Class, "other_non" , bpy.props.FloatProperty() )

#this for ask for annotation
for k, v in props.items() :
    print("key:", k, "value", v )
    setattr( Class, k , bpy.props.FloatProperty() )

bpy.utils.register_class ( Class )
bpy.types.Object.propgr = bpy.props.PointerProperty( type = Class )

so = bpy.context.active_object

so.propgr.non_dinamic = 15.5
so.propgr.dinamic1 = 90.5

print("done")

Comment: Another aproach using what I understand of your code. It work... but with the warning.

Comment: #illegal target for annotations :
"__annotations__" : setattr( Class, "other_non_dinamic" , bpy.props.FloatProperty() )

Comment: Class.__annotations__[k] = bpy.props.FloatProperty()   That work with no warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
name : bpy.props.FloatProperty( name = name )
```

is assigning `bpy.props.FloatProperty( name = name )` to the variable called `name` ( the `name` before the : )

Then you try to assign a value to `so.custom_prop_gr.fl_prop` which does not exist, because you used the variable `name` to create the custom property.

Then in your print command at the end:

```
print( "dina prop (fl_prop): ", so.custom_prop_gr.fl_prop )
```

is also trying to call `so.custom_prop_gr.fl_prop` which does not exist.

Change:

```
so.custom_prop_gr.fl_prop         = 90.5
print( "dina prop (fl_prop): ", so.custom_prop_gr.fl_prop )
```

to:

```
so.custom_prop_gr.name         = 90.5
print( "dina prop (fl_prop): ", so.custom_prop_gr.name )
```

Comment: Try to change:   name : bpy.props.FloatProperty() for a dinamic name not work for me.    f"{name}" : FloatProperty or something like that can't get it work. However help me a lot for discovery what it happen. Thanks.